# Automatically copy image into Power Point on Mac

Tags: macos, clipboard

I'd like to automatically copy an image (that is saved from MATLAB) into a Power Point presentation. Ideally I'd like to copy an image onto the clipboard, and then be able to paste it into Power Point.

Automator will only allow me to copy the file *path*, not the file. I tried running a shell script in Automator with the path, "cat $1 | pbcopy" but that will only copy text or EPS files (which Power Point won't let me directly paste).

Effectively I'd like to automatically grab a .png, .tiff or .jpg (or something like that) and put it on the Mac clipboard. Any ideas? I'm running OS X Lion BTW.

Comment: Assuming you have the PNG from MATLAB, you can just drag it into your PowerPoint slide. I'm not sure what step you're looking to automate if you'll be manually pasting the image once it's in the clipboard. If you wanted to *automatically generate* a PowerPoint slide from your MATLAB image, that's a different story...